Cannot get <kinematic> true </kinematic> property of link to behave as expected - still effected by gravity, other models
I am trying to make a platform move with a constant velocity for testing drone landing approaches. I would like it to move, have collisions, but be otherwise unaffected by physics and forces. As I understand that is the use case for using the <kinematic>true</kinematic> in the link of the model.
But despite my best efforts it does not seem to do anything. The platform is still affected by gravity, and interacts with other parts of the world as normal.
I do not have a lot of .SDF or Gazebo experience so some help would be appreciated!
I have attached the whole .SDF below as it is not long - though the indentation seems to have gotten pretty messed up unfortunately.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sdf version='1.9'>
  <model name='arucotag_moving'>
    <static>false</static>
    <pose>0 0 20.25 0 0 0</pose>

    <link name='base'>
      <gravity>false</gravity>
      <kinematic>true</kinematic>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.5 0.5 0.03</size>
            </box>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode/>
        </friction>
        <bounce/>
        <contact/>
      </surface>
    </geometry>
  </collision>

  <visual name='base_visual'>
    <geometry>
      <box>
        <size>0.5 0.5 0.03</size>
      </box>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <diffuse>1 1 1 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.4 0.4 0.4 1</specular>
      <pbr>
        <metal>
          <albedo_map>model://arucotag_moving/arucotag_staged.png</albedo_map>
        </metal>
      </pbr>
    </material>
  
  </visual>
</link>

